# How can I loop through the title of a plot matplotlib?

Tags: python, loops, matplotlib, plot, title

I'm new to python and trying to plot the PSD in separate plots for each electrode of my EEG dataset via a for loop. The title of the plot should include the respective electrode name.

Here is the code I use to load the data from a .txt file:

```
k = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\LPC\Desktop\rest txt 7min\AB24_rest_asr_ICA_MARA_7min.txt',usecols=['AFp2','F9','AFF5h','AFF1h','AFF2h','AFF6h','F10','FFT9h','FFT7h','FFC5h','FFC3h','FFC1h','FFC2h','FFC4h','FFC6h','FFT8h','FFT10h','FC1','FCz','FC2','FTT9h','FTT7h','FCC5h','FCC3h','FCC1h','FCC2h','FCC4h','FCC6h','FTT8h','FTT10h','Cz','TTP7h','CCP5h','CCP3h','CCP1h','CCP2h','CCP4h','CCP6h','TTP8h','CPz','TPP9h','TPP7h','CPP5h','CPP3h','CPP1h','CPP2h','CPP4h','CPP6h','TPP8h','TPP10h','Pz','PPO1h','PPO2h','P9','PPO9h','POO1','POO2','PPO10h','P10','POO9h','OI1h','OI2h','POO10h'], sep=",")
```

```
k.columns = ['AFp2','F9','AFF5h','AFF1h','AFF2h','AFF6h','F10','FFT9h','FFT7h','FFC5h','FFC3h','FFC1h','FFC2h','FFC4h','FFC6h','FFT8h','FFT10h','FC1','FCz','FC2','FTT9h','FTT7h','FCC5h','FCC3h','FCC1h','FCC2h','FCC4h','FCC6h','FTT8h','FTT10h','Cz','TTP7h','CCP5h','CCP3h','CCP1h','CCP2h','CCP4h','CCP6h','TTP8h','CPz','TPP9h','TPP7h','CPP5h','CPP3h','CPP1h','CPP2h','CPP4h','CPP6h','TPP8h','TPP10h','Pz','PPO1h','PPO2h','P9','PPO9h','POO1','POO2','PPO10h','P10','POO9h','OI1h','OI2h','POO10h']
```

I don't know if this way of doing is useful, but I try to have k to contain the data and k.columns to call the columns.

Then I use the following for loop:

```
for columns in k:
    freqs, psd = signal.welch(k[columns], fs=500, 
                              window='hanning',nperseg=40, noverlap=20, scaling='density', average='mean')
    plt.figure(figsize=(5, 4))
    plt.plot(freqs, psd)
    plt.title('PSD: power spectral density')
    plt.xlabel('Frequency')
    plt.ylabel('Power')
    plt.axis([0,50, -1, 5]) 
plt.show()
```

How can I add a loop in the title of the plot that contains the electrode name?

Thank you very much for your precious help! :)

Comment: Use [f-string formatting](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/) `plt.title(f'PSD: power spectral density for {columns}')`? You probably will also benefit from getting familiar with [subplots and axis objects](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/subplots_demo.html).

Comment: Perfect!! Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response from @Mr.T is really helpful!!

Use f-string formatting `plt.title(f'PSD: power spectral density for {columns}')`? You probably will also benefit from getting familiar with subplots and axis objects. – Mr. T